# error libxml2 not found on installing gokogiri on windows

Tags: go, libxml2, gokogiri

I'm trying to install [gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) on Windows 8 machine following instructions in their github page :

> To install:
>
> - sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
> - go get github.com/moovweb/gokogiri

skipping the first command (as it isn't available on Windows), I get the following error :

[image]

What is the error complaining about? Should I install libxml-2.0 manually before retrying the "go get" command?

**UPDATE :**

The following are the steps I've done, each step based on error message I get from retrying the `go get` command after completing the previous step :

- Download `pkg-config_0.26-1_win32.zip` from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies), unzip/extract, and add the `bin` folder to `path` environment variable
- Donwload `libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86.7z` from [here](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit), unzip. Create new environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and add libxml's `\lib\pkgconfig` folder location to the env variable.
- Donwload and install tdm64-gcc from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/tdm-gcc/TDM-GCC%20Installer/tdm64-gcc-4.8.1.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Ftdm-gcc.tdragon.net%2F&ts=1380861880&use_mirror=superb-dca2)

Now the error message is as follow. What should I do next? How to properly make `gcc` aware of the location of my libxml2 files?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not using MinGW. I also have liteIDE (just like the OP there) and it's fine to build & run some of go codes I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a space in your path to libxml.

option 1: remove libxml and reinstall it at a path without spaces (not program files)

option 2 (might not work for gcc) in the enviroment variable points to libxml (including your path) use quotes around the name path to libxml

Comment: The reason makes perfect sense. Moving libxml to a folder that doesn't contain space (and update env. variable accordingly) solves error in the 2nd screenshot above.Now I'm moving on to the next error message