# How to install gokogiri on Windows?

Tags: go, libxml2, gokogiri

I'm trying to install [gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) on Windows 8 machine, and these are steps that I have done so far :

- Download `pkg-config_0.26-1_win32.zip` from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies), unzip/extract, and add the `bin` folder to `path` environment variable
- Donwload `libxml2-2.9.2-win32-x86.7z` from [here](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit), unzip to a location which path doesn't contain space(s) (otherwise [`gcc` won't be able to find the location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960805/error-libxml2-not-found-on-installing-gokogiri-on-windows)). Create new environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and add libxml's `\lib\pkgconfig` folder location to the env variable.
- Donwload and install tdm64-gcc from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/tdm-gcc/TDM-GCC%20Installer/tdm64-gcc-4.8.1.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Ftdm-gcc.tdragon.net%2F&ts=1380861880&use_mirror=superb-dca2)
- run the following command (as suggested in the GitHub link above) : `go get github.com/moovweb/gokogiri`

but then I get this error :

[image]

What is the error message complaining about now? If I need to download [`icnov`](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit/) manually, how then I put it together with `libxml2` to work properly?

Comment: try to install libiconv from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html - installation instructions).
you don't need to worry about the integration between libxml2 and iconv, because gcc will do that for you.

Comment: @bshuster13 Thanks for your response. I downloaded the installer, installed to `C:\Lib\GnuWin32`, add the path `C:\Lib\GnuWin32\bin` to env. variable (not sure if this last step is necessary). But still the same error when I retry the `go get` command

Comment: har07 is there any C:\Lib\libiconv-1.7-win32-x86/include/" directory or something similar?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I left this over night. Yes, I do have that 'include' directory