# "fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory" on compiling libxml2

Tags: c++, go, compilation, pkg-config, gokogiri

I'm trying to install [gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) on Windows 8 PC by running this command : `go get github.com/moovweb/gokogiri`, but then I get the error in title (full error message at the bottom of question).

[`gokogiri` has dependency to `libxml2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960805/error-libxml2-not-found-on-installing-gokogiri-on-windows) and in turn, `libxml2` seems dependent on `iconv`. I guess I need to change `libxml-2.0.pc` file, which looks like a configuration file, to tell location of `incov` files which I've downloaded separately. But I'm not sure which part of `libxml-2.0.pc` I need to modify and how? Every modification I've tried so far didn't solve the error.

**libxml-2.0.pc**

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
modules=1

Name: libXML
Version: 2.9.2
Description: libXML library version2.
Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lxml2
Libs.private:   -L/usr/local/lib -lz  -L/usr/local/lib -liconv  -lws2_32 
Cflags: -I${includedir}/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include
```

**error message :**

[image]

Comment: Check if `libiconv` is available.

Comment: Yes it is available. At the time I posted the question, I have downloaded `libiconv` separately, it is in path : `C:\Lib\iconv-1.14-win32-x86`.